# Fix branch confusion in Git using Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have been working and apparently have not been working on a branch, which I did not realize. Now I have a lot of commits and cannot push to the remote branch

[image]

When I look at the history of the repo I'm a bit confused. I see the Master branch well down the commit list. Yet the blue line, which I think is supposed to represent the Master branch, continues, but when I try to check out the master it is giving me a warning seen below.

[image]

[image]

I don't have a lot of branches, this is my first large project so I am really just working on the master branch. I only need the master branch right now. So I don't mind if I cannot reach other branches or whatnot. At this stage, I just need to know my files are in a good state and need to get working again! Thanks for any help you can give in helping me understand what this all means.

Comment: Not in sourcetree, but you really just need to create a branch from your current floating head (`git branch switch -c tempbranch`) then merge it to master(`git checkout master; git merge tempbranch`), and delete temp branch(`git branch -d tempbranch`).

Comment: Thanks @JohnPavek I was able to do that in sourcetree! If you want to make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your detached head can actually become a branch. From your current HEAD you can do `git switch -c tempbranch`. Then merge your temp branch to master, `git switch master; git merge tempbranch` finally. Clean your workspace with `git branch -d tempbranch`.

To summarize the commands:

```
git switch -c tempbranch
git switch master
git merge tempbranch
git branch -d tempbranch
```